# Import DUMP table, special chars in VALUES

Tags: python, mysql

I have a dump of a mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `smf_messages` (
  `id_msg` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   etc.
   ...
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

--
-- Dumping data for table `smf_messages`
--

INSERT INTO `smf_messages` (`id_msg`,
etc.
... ) VALUES
(1, 1, 5, 1673905780, 0, 1, 'Welcome&nbsp;to&nbsp;&quot;SMF!&quot;',
etc.
...
, 1, 0);
```

The usual code to import the SQL dump file fails:

```
with open(dump_file, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    commands = lines.replace('&nbsp;', ' ').split(';')
```

It fails, because it splits lines at the HTML symbols like `"&nbsp;"`

How can I make this work?

Comment: I see nothing to say that the "columns" are quoted.  Meanwhile, the "replace" does not care about quites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the data into a MySQL table.  Do *not* use python for this step.  Use `LOAD DATA` of MySQL.
2. *Then* manipulate the text as needed.  Either user SQL statements or `SELECT` the data you need to process.